# How to determine where the content ends in pdf using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am creating pdf file using `PdfSharp`.
I have one fix existing pdf file with one page and some content in it. I want to start adding my contents right after the existing content.

Is there anything in `PdfSharp` from which I can determine where the last element or section ends?
Any reference will be great.

Comment: What elements do you have in the pdf file thus far? If you always have the same content then you just need to add any element as a placeholder and add the content after that.

Comment: If you dont always have the same content then figure out what could be the type of element that you add last and go through the list of that type of element until you get to the last element. Then just add your new content after that element.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to this question [How to add DocumentLink to existing PDF file using PdfSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607056/how-to-add-documentlink-to-existing-pdf-file-using-pdfsharp). You can simply take the AddDocumentLink code and get the highest XY coordinate and that should be enough to figure where to append additional content.