# How to add DocumentLink to existing PDF file using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have several pdf files. and I want to combine all of them in one which I can do using PDFSharp.

But I also want **Table Of Contents** at the top with **DocumentLink**.

Table of content is separately created using Migradoc which looks as below.

[image]

My question is is there any way in pdfsharp using which I can add Document link on the Document name like Document1, Document2 which redirects to respective pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing MigraDoc and PDFsharp you can get it done.

You can add a `Tag` to the paragraphs that you want to link. While the created PDF and the MigraDoc document are still open, you can combine the PDFs and add the links. In PDFsharp you specify the rectangle you want to turn into a link. If you want a special look for the links, you have to set the look in MigraDoc already.

Finding the tagged paragraphs in the document to add the links is tricky and I don't have a sample at hand.
Here is code that adds the pages one by one:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3172
Add the links after adding each MigraDoc page with the table of contents.
See this post on the PDFsharp forum to get started:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9694#p9694